# C# how to get current class instance equivalent to self php

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

Lets suppose we have these classes:

```
class A {
    public string attr = "Class A";

    public static void getAttribute(){
         self currentClass = new self(); // equivalent to php
         Console.Write("Attribute : " + currentClass.attr);
    }
}

Class B : A {
    public string attr = "Class B";
}

B = new B();
B.getAttribute();
```

I want `B.getAttribute();` to print `Attribute: Class B`. How can I do this?

Comment: .Net member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably know what you are trying to do, but I have to tell you that this kind of PHP approach makes no sense in C#. I discourage you from using it.

```
public class A
{
    private String attr = "Class A";

    public static String getAttribute()
    {
        return (new A()).attr;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private String attr = "Class B";

    public static String getAttribute()
    {
        return (new B()).attr;
    }
}
```

Comment: but how can i get current class instance?

Comment: The poster's getAttribute() method is static, which will not work. Static members cannot be overridden.

Comment: It won't work as static, obviously, but I think the poster is asking conceptually how to make it work in C#. If he needs to make getAttribute static, then getAttribute() will need to take the object as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamentally impossible.

`B.getAttribute()` compiles to `A.getAttribute()`.

Comment: is any way to solve this i know the answer in php i just want the current class insctance

Comment: @AntonioPapa: No.  You should rethink your design; static methods should not interact with derived classes.

Comment: Ok but if its not static how can i do it?

Comment: @AntonioPapa: By using `virtual` methods and overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to do something like that in C#, I think the answer would be along these lines:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual string attr 
    {       
        get { return "Class A" }
    }

    public void getAttribute(){
         Console.Write("Attribute : " + attr);
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override string attr 
    {       
        get { return "Class B"; }
    }
}

var b = new B();

b.getAttribute();
```

Regarding my comment in the other answer, if you needed getAttribute to be static, you could implement it this way:

```
public static void getAttribute(A obj){
     Console.Write("Attribute : " + obj.attr);
}
```

You would then call it like this:

```
var b = new B();
A.getAttribute(b);
```

Comment: ok thank you but how can i get an instance of current class? like currentClass.attr = "some text "

Comment: @AntonioPapa I think you may want to look at the `this` keyword http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @AntonioPapa you would just do string val = this.attr; And actually, this is redundant and often just used for clarity. If you're in an instance method of the class, you can simply use attr like a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You get the current class instance by the 'this' keyword. Obviously you cannot access that in a static method since by definition a static method executes without the context of a particular instance.

On the other hand, to access a member variable/property/method from inside the same class, you don't need the 'this' keyword at all, since it's implicit.